# How do I extract a ZIP file on the fly with DotNetZip?

Tags: c#, azure, stream, zip, dotnetzip

In my Windows Azure code I want to download a ZIP file from Blob Storage and unzip it on the fly and store the unzipped contents to the disk. This way I save on first writing the file to the disk and then reading it when doing the extraction.

I'm trying to use DotNetZip for that.

The ZIP file is originally very big, so it is cut into pieces (not multipart archive, but a plain ZIP archive, just cut into smaller files) and each piece is uploaded into Blob Storage. I know how to iterate through all the parts and open each blob when neededn

Azure SDK has `CloudBlob.OpenRead()` that returns a `Stream` descendant.

DotNetZip has `ZipInputStream` class that has a constructor accepting a `Stream`.

How do I connect these pieces together so that I can download the ZIP file pieces one by one and get them extracted on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own stream class that will return data from the corresponding CloudBlob according to its position.

Then use this class a input stream for your `ZipInputStream`.

```
public sealed class ZipBlobStream : Stream
{
...
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.stream.aspx